# Using pagination with group by in Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-pagination

I have a problem. I have a code to retrieve all the data with group by that goes like this.

```
public function getAllDokumen()
    {
        $dokumen = Dokumen::get()->groupBy('debitur_id')->all();
        return $dokumen;
    }
```

And then, I need to display it like this

```
@foreach ($allDokumen as $dok)
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="11">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                        <td rowspan="11">{{ $dok->first()->debitur->no_debitur }}</td>
                        <td rowspan="11">{{ $dok->first()->debitur->nama_debitur }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (['PPJB', 'AJB', 'SKMHT', 'APHT', 'PH', 'SHT', 'IMB', 'Sertipikat', 'PK', 'CN'] as $jenis)
                        @php
                            $d = $dok->where('jenis', $jenis)->first();
                        @endphp
                        @if ($d)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $jenis }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @if ($d->status_pinjaman == 0)
                                        Tersedia
                                    @elseif ($d->status_keluar == 1)
                                        Keluar
                                    @elseif ($d->status_pinjaman == 1)
                                        Dipinjam
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @else
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $jenis }}</td>
                                <td>Tidak Tersedia</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach

<div class="mt-4 items-center">
        {{ $allDokumen->links() }}
    </div>
```

Is there any way to paginate the result from indexDokumen()

I have tried to just using `paginate()`, but the result isn't same as I want. I tried using `paginate()->groupBy('debitur_id')`, but I can't use the `links()` method of pagination.

Comment: I suggest you to create a table for 'jenis' including a numeric order, then you can select `jenis left join documens` and manage the change of the jenis into the view

Comment: is it needed to make pagination of debitur?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getAllDokumen()
{    $currentPage = request()->get('page', 1);
    $dokumen = Dokumen::with('debitur')
               ->selectRaw('*, COUNT(*) as total')
               ->groupBy('debitur_id')
               ->paginate(10, ['*'], 'page', $currentPage);
    return $dokumen;
}
```

Comment: is there any change that needed for livewire?